# Pass name in jQuery form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I do not know why the following line will not function properly:

```
$('form[name="updateNetwork"]').unbind('submit').submit();
```

I can submit my form with

```
$("form").unbind('submit').submit();
```

However doing so will not pass the name attribute of the form which my backend code must identify in order to properly process the form submission.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does the form have a `name` attribute?

Comment: Please check the rendered html in firebug or chrome console for the name attribute and its value

Comment: @OscarPaz the submit button contains the name attribute i.e.:    <input type="submit" name="updateNetwork" value="Add/Update Network" />.  I've attempted to place the name attribute in the MVC helper form link but it appends it to the url as part of the actionlink not as a name attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have only one form in your page, and that the only reason you're trying to select it with the name attribute in jQuery is so that jQuery will send the name of the form to the server.

Well, that won't work. Once you get a reference to your form via jQuery, it doesn not matter which selector you had used. If what you want is to send a `name` parameter to your backend code with the form name, use a hidden input inside the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="updateNetwork" />
```

Then, you can get a reference to the form any way you want. The best one, as stated by @anvlasop, is to give your form an `id` attribute.

*EDITED*

You were creating the jQuery form object in a wrong way. If you have this:

```
<input type="submit" name="updateNetwork" />
```

then you can't do this:

```
$('form[name="updateNetwork"]).submit();
```

I assume that you're calling this method, `submit()`, inside the event handler of the `submit` event. Don't do that! What you should do, is to only canll `preventDefault` if there is an error in the validation, and let the form be sent otherwise:

```
//Never do this:
$('form').bind('submit', function(e) {
    var valid;
    //code to validate
    e.preventDefault();

    if (valid) $('form').unbind('submit').submit();
 });
```

Do this:

```
$('form').bind('submit', function(e) {
   var valid;
   try {
       //code to validate
   } catch (error) {
       valid = false;
   }
   if (!valid) e.preventDefault();
});
```

This also will prevent the sending of the form is there is an exception during validation.

Comment: I was thinking the same as you had mentioned in this reply.  However, when I attempt to add such a hidden field to my MVC form it breaks the e.preventDefault(); action which was stopping the submission of the form till all values were successfully tested against a regex expression for validation.

Comment: Maybe because you're iterating through all the inputs in the form? You may have to change the validator. Or, if there is a `name` attribute in the `submit` button ... Is that `name` in the submit button `updateNetwork`?

Comment: Yes, I am iterating through all inputs of the same name to validate the input into each field.  I did have the name attribute in the submit button such as: <input type="submit" name="updateNetwork" value="Add/Update Network" />. Removing the name attribute in the submit button and adding the hidden field with name="updateNetwork", still broke the preventDefault(), however the form is received in my backend with the "updateNetwork" name attribute. This is not a solution because this would allow the user to submit without proper verification of entered text.

Comment: OscarPaz thank you for your assistance, with your help I resolved this issue.  After some more debugging I found that the preventDefault() was preventing the submission of the form however I was iterating through two different sets of form fields and setting the result to the same bool, so if the second set was true (even if the first wasn't) it was allowing the form to submit.  I created a separate bool for each set of inputs and checked if both bools are true to permit submission.

Answer (score 1):

You can give an id to your form. Try something like this html code:

```
<form id='form_id'>
     //your form elements here...
</form>
```

Then, with jQuery you can have a reference to the form like this:

```
$("#form_id").unbind('submit').submit();
```